# Saving dynamic global data(session-token) in laravel?

Tags: php, heroku, laravel

I'm running a laravel app that draws some data from facebook using https://graph.facebook.com/search api. In order to do this, I need to be authenticated as a user. Facebook keeps track of this through an access token. The users of the app aren't authenticated, but rather, an admin of the site authenticates with facebook and then the app uses that persons access-token.

I'm not sure how to save the access token in the app. Currently, I have created a table with a single data-entry in it, but if feels kind of like...not really what tables are meant for. To make things more complicated, I run the app on a service called Pagodabox(similar to Heroku). In pagodabox the app can't write to files, all updates are commited via git, so a config file isn't an option either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of Heroku's config/environment variables for this.

```
heroku config:set FB_ACCESS_TOKEN="abc123etcloremipsum-123456"
```

And then in your PHP code, you would access this from

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=" . env('FB_ACCESS_TOKEN');
```